# WebApi Controller Lifecycle

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, authorization, asp.net-web-api2, lifecycle

So, here's the deal.

I have a WebApi with a number of Controllers. I have an Identity Server configured to to Authentication. This all works.

When I make a call on the API and I pass the appropriate token, if I put a breakpoint in any of the Actions of the Controller, the User object is properly populated.

Now, the code that the API Actions execute needs data related to the authenticated user. If I attempt to execute this code in the constructor of the Controller my code fails because User is not yet properly populated.

So, to my question: is there some element of the Controller's lifecycle, that I have yet to discover, that will allow me to execute code for every call on the Controller (like it would in the constructor) but where the User object has been properly populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User is only assigned well after the controller is created. There are no events on ApiControllers that you can handle to do that. The most common way to this is to extract a method that retrieves the extra information and call it in every action

Comment: I had a horrible feeling that that was the case.

Comment: Overriding ApiController.User would seem to be a way to address this, but alas the property is not virtual and thus cannot be overridden.  Could be fixed by forking the source.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some kind of token(encrypted UserId/Guid) in the header. You can use the header variable/token to get the User object in the controller side.